# Save Data from table view on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, maps, core-location

I need to save data from Tableview on selection. The data is 'search results' from `mapView` which displays "State /Code/ Address".

```
let addressLine = String(
        format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
        // street number
        selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
        firstSpace,
        // street name
        selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
        comma,
        // city
        selectedItem.locality ?? "",
        secondSpace,
        // state
        selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
    )
    return addressLine
}
```

Comment: What do you mean save data on selection ?

Comment: Im displaying search results of map in tableview and want to save details on selection.. Ex when i search for wallmart i get results of location where its displayed .... alocation....
                          blocation........... on selection of b location i would to save coordinates and address also